# Why is Shift + C taking me to a grey screen?

Tags: 3d-view

Really quick question, whenever I utilize `Shift + C` my viewport seemingly goes blank!

[image: The viewport, entirely blank, save for the 3D cursor.]

I've found that it's just really zoomed out, after scrolling in about 30 times.

I've made sure there isn't anything huge or extending super far out by unhiding everything, selecting everything, entering edit mode, entering wireframe mode, manually selecting everything in view with box selection, inverting my selection, and deleting all verticies.

I've closed my 3D viewport and created a new one as mentioned [here](https://blenderartists.org/t/shift-c-to-center-cursor-at-world-origin-model-vanishes/350660/10), but that doesn't seem to help either.

What's causing this?

You can find the .blend file [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1an2xt_uYxjvhiURm1PRqUu7WefyeSMiB/view?usp=sharing)! Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you have a nurbs path object called "HairFront" under the "hair" collection that doesn't seem to have anything in edit mode, that's causing blender to zoom out really far when hitting shift + C.

If it happens again, you can use "view > frame selected" in the 3D viewport and that'll do the same thing as shift + C except only for objects that are currently selected. You can use that to help find the culprit.

Comment: Thank you so much!!